# Transformer inductive kick?

Tags: transformer

Could someone help me understand the behavior in this DC circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhKTAC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When I press SW1 and hold it down briefly, the green LED flashes and goes out (while I'm still holding down SW1.)  Then when I release SW1, the red LED flashes and goes out.

This repeats every time I press and release SW1.

I think I understand that when I press and hold SW1, the change in current through the primary coil from 0A to some higher value induces a very brief voltage/current in the secondary coil and this causes the green LED to flash.  Please correct me if this is wrong.

I have three questions:

1. Why does the red LED flash when I release SW1?
2. Why is the secondary coil current counter-clockwise when I press SW1?
3. Why is the secondary coil current clockwise when I release SW1?

Comment: Switched DC is AC, it is no DC transformer.

Comment: If you want more reliable feedback, try putting the switch on the other site of the transformer. This should give you different timings.

Comment: With the DC source, wouldn't that cause a short circuit in the primary coil side?

Comment: @AnnetteGates - yes -  DC applied to the primary will rise until I = V/Rprimary. Or in an ideal transformer with Rprimary=0 current will rise towards infinity :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your questions are valid because, with the dot notation shown on your windings, what you describe as happening, should never happen. Hence, I suspect that you have the transformer wired like this (my dots are in red): -

[image]

When you activate SW1 current ramps-up in the primary winding. This induces a secondary voltage that is positive at the secondary dot. This forces current into the green LED and illuminates it. Green will only stay illuminated for a short time because, an indefinite ramping current is not available from V1 and so, after a short time, the secondary induced voltage falls to zero.

At this point, the core is magnetized by the primary current and, when SW1 opens, the flux tails-off and a positive secondary voltage is now seen on the undotted secondary wire. This forces current into the red LED.

Of course, if your LEDs are wired backwards then the dots (as you originally showed them) are OK.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn’t call it a DC circuit, since the interesting behavior your observe is transient – that’s what AC is :)

The secondary voltage can be explained simply by Faraday’s law.

Right after the push button is pressed, magnetic flux builds up in the core, up to a static maximum level. The output voltage’s polarity follows the direction of this change.

After the button is released, the magnetic field collapses, and the output voltage polarity follows this – the direction of the change in flux is opposite from when the button was first pressed.

The LEDs only flash briefly because the output voltage follows the slope of the changing flux. Once the flux has stabilized at either 0 or a maximum level, the output voltage is zero since the flux is not changing anymore. The slope is 0.

Answer (score 3):

Any change in the primary current will induce current in the secondary.

The direction of the current change in the primary will affect the direction of current in the secondary.

When you close the switch, you will get a current pulse in the secondary as the primary current rises - when the primary current is stable, the secondary current will fall to zero.

Opening the switch will cause the primary current to drop to zero, inducing a pulse of current in the opposite polarity in the secondary.

Answer (score 1):

Note that with an 'ideal' transformer, the green LED would remain on continuously when the switch is closed, and the red would *not* light when the switch is opened. In addition, the 1:14 turns ratio would put 14*3 across the LEDs which would cause them to fail.

When you begin to add non-idealities to the transformer, behaviour changes.

1. If you include magnetizing inductance, then the green will light, but the input current will build up (in the magnetizing L) indefinitely. When the switch opens, the magnetizing inductance will deflux (that's a word !), and (by transformer action) the red LED will light until the energy is discharged.
2. If you include core losses, core saturation and winding resistances, then the currents won't build indefinitely.
3. If you include leakage inductance, the LED current will take a short time to build up. When you open the switch, it will take a short while for the currents to reverse direction and invert the LEDs.

Comment: When you say "would remain on indefinitely" it would be useful to add that the current would continue to rise and would rapidly assume humungous [tm] values .

Answer (score 1):

You should try a different circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdlGZx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: This would change the behaviour BUT the opposite polarity LED would still flash on release.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon But you can  the opposite polarity LED not only by releasing the switch but also by closing the other switch while holding the switch.

Comment: Yes. As I noted, this is changed behaviour. Your answer is not really an answer to the question but does provide useful comment.